# What the first/second part of the day referring to?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I heard this phrase in a weather broadcast on a radio. It says something like:

> on the first part of the day, the temperature is ... and on the second part of the day, the temperature is ...

My question is whether the first part of the day is referring to the **morning** or the whole day time, and the second part of the day is referring to the **afternoon** or the whole night time.

My impression to that context is that they are referring to the morning and afternoon respectively. But I am not quite sure about it. Appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: There is no specific meaning to "first part," etc.  Without context, this is difficult to answer.  For example, if the speaker is talking about the business day, then "first part" may refer to before lunch and "second part" to after lunch.  But, without knowing that the speaker is talking about a business day, we don't know if that is what the parts refer to.  Can you link us to the entire broadcast?  Can you tell us more about it?

Comment: @JBH I heard this one a live radio broadcast, so I don't have the link handy. Anyways, I do learn something from your comment here. Thanks!